# Wordpress с плагином "userpress"

Tags: wordpress

Добрый день. На сайте использую плагин `userPress` для организации статей в виде `wiki` + `Advanced Custom Fields`.
Со стороны администратора всё работает чудесно. А как кастомизировать стандартную форму на фронтенде с использованием этих самых кастомных полей? Может кто делал подобное. Документация для userpress очень бедненькая и небольшая.
Может кто сталкивался с подобной задачей.

Answer (score 1):

Надо было всего лишь написать так:

```
            <?php acf_form(); ?>
```